# Problems registering a dll in Windows Server 2003

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, regsvr32

I have a dll (build using C++ and MFC) and when I try to register

> regsvr32 myDll.dll

the prompt shows no errors and also doesn't show that the dll has been registered but on the Task Manager the process "**regsvr32.exe*32**" get "**stuck**" (the process doesn't consume any CPU, doesn't die and just stay there until I kill him).

The problem started after I added [CreateTimerQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682483(v=vs.85).aspx) on my code and only occurs on Windows Server 2003.

Accordingly to the documentation this function it's accepted on Window Server 2003.

My dll it's compiled in 32-bits and I'm using the regsvr32 inside the sysWOW64 but also tried using the one inside system32.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing [funny things](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873) in your `DllMain` or `DllRegisterServer`?

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help

Comment: @Penachia You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to debug where the process hangs. Please reference ["Use Process Explorer to obtain application hangs information"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdnts/2006/11/24/how-to-debug-application-crashhang-in-production-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like others have also experienced deadlocks with `CreateTimerQueue` in `DllMain` - see [this](https://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/STQe8wYW/avoiding-restrictions-of-dllmain-need-sanity-check-please). So rework your code so that the function is not called from `DllMain`.